# Python: Retrieving information from nested divs of HTML code

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, nested

I'm trying to extract data from individual divs from HTML code using BeautifulSoup.

Here's an example div that's a result of using `html.find_all('div')`:

```
<div style="position: relative; background: background.png">
    <img class="onclick" onclick="ajax_request()" title="Text1"/>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 2px; right: 3px;">
        Text2
    </div>
</div>
```

**How can I find `background.png`, `Text1` and `Text2` in the above code?**

I've tried using `div.attrs`, but the only option is `style` that belongs to the first div (no information about the img tag or nested div).  Additionally, `div['style']`returns a string, so I'm not sure how to retrieve only the `background` value without using regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected result, try the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<div style="position: relative; background: background.png">
    <img class="onclick" onclick="ajax_request()" title="Text1"/>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 2px; right: 3px;">
        Text2
    </div>
</div>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

background = soup.find("div")["style"].split(":")[-1].strip()
text1 = soup.find("img")["title"]
text2 = soup.find("div").get_text(strip=True)
```